# Single quote vs double quote hell in PHP

Tags: php, quotes

I have found myself in the ' and " hell. Can't figure out why this is not working. Would appreciate some fresh experienced over it. Thanks

```
foreach($channels as $channel)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$channel['id'].'" '.($channel['id'] == 2) ? 'selected' : ''.'>'.$channel['name'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and use this syntax: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: Try putting some parenthesis around `($channel['id'] == 2) ? 'selected' : ''`

Comment: Also you don't need the `)` you have immediately after `== 2)`.  So basically move that closing `)` from its current position to after the `''` as Michel suggests.  `($channel['id'] == 2 ? 'selected' : '')`

Comment: Move the ) to the end? OMG! yes that works. Thanks Michel and duncan

Answer (score 0):

This is where PHP's [alternative syntax for control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) really shines as a templating syntax

```php
foreach ($channels as $channel): ?>
<option
  value="<?= htmlspecialchars($channel['id']) ?>"
  <?= $channel['id'] == 2 ? 'selected' : '' ?>
>
  <?= htmlspecialchars($channel['name']) ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```